# How to count time between occurrences (and duration of occurrence)

Tags: r

I am dealing with the following challenge and would greatly appreciate any help.

Consider I have a data table with the following information.

```
Store   Day           In stock ?  Out of stock ?
Store A 01 - 01 - 19  1           0
Store A 02 - 01 - 19  0           1
Store A 03 - 01 - 19  0           1
Store A 04 - 01 - 19  1           0
Store A 05 - 01 - 19  1           0
Store A 06 - 01 - 19  0           1
Store A 07 - 01 - 19  0           1
Store A       …       0           1
Store B 01 - 01 - 19  1           0
Store B 02 - 01 - 19  0           1
Store B       …       0           1
```

For each store, I want to count the number of days for which is has consecutively been in or out of stock. These two columns are binary, and mutually exclusive. So for store A, the result would be:

```
Store     Duration in stock   Duration out of stock  
Store A   1
Store A                       2
Store A   2
Store A                       3
```

I need to do this for a large dataset (hourly values for hundreds of stores), and thus would like to automate this. Furthermore, I want to do further analysis on the 'in stock duration' and 'out of stock duration', such as average values, extremes, percentiles etc. Therefore, the data needs to be organized in such a way that this would be possible.

I have not found a solution to this problem yet. Any insight would be nice!

Below comma seperated values:

```
Store;Day;In stock?;Out of stock?
Store A;01-01-19;1;0
Store A;02-01-19;0;1
Store A;03-01-19;0;1
Store A;04-01-19;1;0
Store A;05-01-19;1;0
Store A;06-01-19;0;1
Store A;07-01-19;0;1
Store A;…;0;1
Store B;01-01-19;1;0
Store B;02-01-19;0;1
Store B;…;0;1
```

Comment: Can you use `dput` to show the data

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot share the data (confidential), and the file is too large as well. Anyways, the store and in/out of stock are just an analogue of my actual dataset. The basis question I am asking is how to count the number of rows ('time') between a change in a binary value in a certain column. I thought explaining this as above would be helpful to clarify my goal.

Comment: I understand, but if I have to copy/paste the data you showed, it is a bit of an effort.  I thought you wouldn't mind making it easier for those who want to help

Comment: Apologies, not an expert on how to use Stack Overflow and wanted the data to look neat. I have added the comma seperated values at the end of the post, hope this helps!

Comment: If you highlight the code and click the `{}` button (or manually prepend each line with four whitespace) it will be nicely formatted.

Comment: In your data, is there guaranteed to be one row for each day? No skips, no twice a day?

Comment: Are the `U+2026`s (ellipses) an actual part of your data, or something you've added?

Comment: Ellipses are something I have added to highlight that the actual data set is longer, the data is completely neat. Guaranteed only one row per time instant. No skips, not twice a day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach with `dplyr`. First, I convert the date column into a date using lubridate, assuming that it's in day-month-year (hence dmy) order.

Then, for each store, count which "stock period" we're in, where it's a new one each time it switches between in and out of stock.

Using that and the store, I sum the numbers in each column.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(Day = lubridate::dmy(Day)) %>%
  group_by(Store) %>%
  mutate(stock_period = cumsum(In_stock != lag(In_stock, default = ""))) %>%
  group_by(Store, stock_period) %>%
  summarise(start = min(Day),
            end   = max(Day),
            In_stock = sum(In_stock), 
            Out_of_stock = sum(Out_of_stock))

# A tibble: 6 x 6
# Groups:   Store [2]
  Store   stock_period start      end        In_stock Out_of_stock
  <chr>          <int> <date>     <date>        <int>        <int>
1 Store A            1 2019-01-01 2019-01-01        1            0
2 Store A            2 2019-01-02 2019-01-03        0            2
3 Store A            3 2019-01-04 2019-01-05        2            0
4 Store A            4 2019-01-06 2019-01-07        0            2
5 Store B            1 2019-01-01 2019-01-01        1            0
6 Store B            2 2019-01-02 2019-01-02        0            1
```

Using this source data:

```
df <- read.table(header = T, stringsAsFactors = F,
  text = "Store Day In_stock Out_of_stock
'Store A' 01-01-19 1 0
'Store A' 02-01-19 0 1
'Store A' 03-01-19 0 1
'Store A' 04-01-19 1 0
'Store A' 05-01-19 1 0
'Store A' 06-01-19 0 1
'Store A' 07-01-19 0 1
'Store B' 01-01-19 1 0
'Store B' 02-01-19 0 1")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing, indeed this works! Since I am a bit more familiar with dplyr, I myself prefer your solution. Verified this first by doing in on the 'test' data I shared, but also modified it to work on my data and it does exactly what I needit to do. Great help!

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this is close enough.

But first to clarify something.
When we say "show us your data", we don't demand a facsimile of what you're working with, but rather something that is functionally the same, or analogous, to your data. Often this means you just limit the number of rows you include, while other times it involves changing the names of column names or values due to privacy concerns, but the data is kept the same, as far as processing is concerned.

First my attempt at reproducing something resembling your data

```
set.seed(4)

Day <- as.Date(0:8, origin="2019-01-01")
Store <- rep(paste("Store", LETTERS[1:3]), each=length(Day))
In <- sample(c(0, 0, 1), length(Store), rep=TRUE)
Out <- abs(In - 1)
Day <- format(rep(Day, length=length(Store)), "%d - %m - %y")

dtf <- data.frame(Store, Day, In, Out)
head(dtf)
#     Store          Day In Out
# 1 Store A 01 - 01 - 19  0   1
# 2 Store A 02 - 01 - 19  0   1
# 3 Store A 03 - 01 - 19  0   1
# 4 Store A 04 - 01 - 19  0   1
# 5 Store A 05 - 01 - 19  1   0
```

Given this data, the following should produce the desired result.

```
io <- with(dtf, tapply(In, Store, function(x) as.data.frame(rle(x)[1:2])))
io <- do.call(rbind, io)

iod <- with(io, 
  data.frame(Store=gsub("\\.[0-9]?", "", rownames(io)),
             Duration.in.stock=lengths*values,
             Duration.out.of.stock=lengths*!values
  )
)

iod[iod == 0] <- ""

iod
#      Store Duration.in.stock Duration.out.of.stock
# 1  Store A                                       4
# 2  Store A                 1                      
# 3  Store A                                       1
# 4  Store A                 3                      
# 5  Store B                                       1
# 6  Store B                 1                      
# 7  Store B                                       2
# 8  Store B                 1                      
# 9  Store B                                       2
# 10 Store B                 1                      
# 11 Store B                                       1
# 12 Store C                 4                      
# 13 Store C                                       3
# 14 Store C                 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing, indeed this works! Since I am a bit more familiar with dplyr, I myself prefer the solution of Jon Spring. Thank you very much nonetheless for your help! Have a great day.